# Tikz externalization - Mode: list and make - not able to generate figures

Tags: tikz-pgf, externalize

I'd like to replace some of my .pdf-figures with their .png-version and I stubbled upon this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56708895/tikz-png-output-does-not-output-a-png and I got some issues related to the externalize mode: list and make.

I'd like to use a Makefile and I can generate the desired Makefile but when I try to 'make' the file i receive the following output:

```
process_begin: CreateProcess(NULL, cat main.figlist, ...) failed.
main.makefile:4: pipe: No error
process_begin: CreateProcess(NULL, cat main.figlist, ...) failed.
main.makefile:9: pipe: No error
All images exist now. Use make -B to re-generate them.
```

and the figures are not generated. Due to the fact I've never worked with Makefiles before I can't seem to find my problem here.

MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{external}
\tikzexternalize[mode=list and make]

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw (0,0) -- (1,-1);
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw (0,0) -- (1,1);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Your code seems to work fine if I compile it with the following sequence from the tikz user manual (p. 677): https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q6Qce.png

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Comment: Thanks for your fast response. I was using the mentioned sequence but when I try to generate the figures with `make -f main.makefile` the error above occures. I am working on a Windows machine but I have ghostscript installed and I use MinGW for make. Is there anything else I might have forgotten?